# Polymorphism inheritance not overriding base class method

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

My base class:

```
class Item
{
protected:  
    int count;
    string model_name;
    int item_number;

public:
    Item();
    void input();
}
```

My derived Class:

```
class Bed : public Item
{
private:
    string frame;
    string frameColour;
    string mattress;

public:
    Bed();
    void input();
}
```

for now all my input function is trying to do is output which method is being used:

```
void Item::input()
{ 
    cout<<"Item input"<<endl;
}

void Bed::input()
{
    cout<<" Bed Input"<<endl;
}
```

when I call the function in main I'd like the derived class input to be used but at present the item input is.

Main:

```
vector<Item> v;
Item* item;
item= new Bed;
v.push_back(*item);
v[count].input();
count++;
```

I have followed the method laid out in a book I have but I think i may be confused about how to create new objects stored in the vector.

Any help would be great,
Thanks 
Hx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't marked your method as `virtual`.

Also, because you have a `vector` of objects, not pointers, you'll run into **object slicing**. Although it will compile, it isn't correct.

The proper way is having a vector of pointers or smart pointers.

```
class Item
{
   //....
   virtual void input(); //mark method virtual in base class
};

class Bed : public Item
{
   //....
   virtual void input();
};


vector<Item*> v;
Item* item = new Bed;
v.push_back(item);
//...
//remember to free the memory
for ( int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++ ) 
    delete v[i];
```

Comment: Also, when you have a container of pointers, you may want to wrap that container in a custom class with the same interface, and have its insertion and deletion operations take care of `new`s and `delete`s.

Comment: @suszterpatt that sounds like a smart pointer to me (which already is in the answer).

Comment: I guess technically it's more like a smart container, but more to the point, it's a good exercise for someone who's apparently learning C++. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In base class:

```
virtual void input();
```

In derive class

```
virtual void input() override;
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore maybe `virtual void input() override` in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid object slicing you could either use pointers or references. For the behaviour you're looking for, you must declare the function as `virtual` in the base class.

Sometimes people prefer tu place the virtual keyword in the derived classes as well, to remember the user that the function is virtual, but that's not mandatory.

You should remember as well that using virtual functions has a cost and you should think about it before actually using it.

Comment: The cost of a virtual function should play no role whatsoever in the decision to use them or not. Also, do you mind explaining how you can have a vector of references?

Comment: well in this case, using a reference isn't relevant but if you do: `Base & object = child;` the object isn't sliced (eg in a function call)